# JDBC: ORCLE stored procedures with return-value in batch-processing

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a JDBC connect to a Oracle RDBMS.

I need to call a stored procedure (lets name it foo) that returns a number.

It is working fine if I perform every statement for its own.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i ++)
{
  CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall ("{? = foo (" + i + ")}");
  cst.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
  cst.execute ();
}
```

NOW I like to use batched processing to boost it up the performance. Thats my approach.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement ();
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i ++)
{
  st.addBatch ("{? = foo (" + i + ")}");
}
st.executeBatch ();
```

That does not work.

Error tells me not every variable is assigned. Think it is because there is no registration for the return-value as it is in the working sample above.

If I set the statement to

```
{foo (" + i + ")}
```

to remove the return then I get the error that the procedure is not defined.

How can I handle such a stored procedure with a return-value in batched processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDBC batch processing required an identical prepared statement and a bunch of bind variables.

You violates this with dynamical statement `"{? = foo (" + i + ")}"`  generated for each `i`.

You must use a single statement with two bind variables `"{? = foo (?)}"`

unfortunately this leads to an exception

> Caught: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Stored procedure with out or inout parameters cannot be batched

because there is no possibility to return the  collection of the result function calls from the batch statement.

Fortunately there is a very simple alternative solution. You may use a prepareStatement to simulate the batch-processing
(i.e. you limit the roundtripts to the DB server)

```
 def stmt = con.prepareStatement("select foo(rownum) foo from dual connect by level <= 10")
```

Set the *fetch site* same as the *batch size* and you'll get the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I like to anntoate that is is required to init ALL variables, even the return-value (1st variable). But the registration as a output-variable is not allowed.

Comment: @chris01 you are correct. I added some alternative proposal to workaround this problem.